# How would i execute this command in java?

Tags: java, unix

How would i make a java program find and delete all the files in my computer that have the extension: .jar?

I have the command:

```
find . -type f -name "*.jar" -exec rm -i {} \;
```

I know how to execute commands, but i don't know how to tell it to execute this command.

Comment: Have a look at a Java File IO tutorial.

Comment: Did you try searching for it on the internet first?

Comment: Do you mean; how do you use Runtime.exec()?

Comment: Yeah, Im trying to figure out how the String[] works with commands

Answer (score 1):

Simply, you CAN't delete ALL .jar files on computer. Because your java program needs JVM to run and since jvm uses jar files present under lib of JRE insallation. And in order to run your program you need lib jar files.

Although, you can give it a try with example from mkyong.

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-find-files-with-certain-extension-only/

Comment: Yes he CAN! (yet he SHOULDN'T)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a FilenameFilter to see if files match your pattern.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html

Once you have found a file you want to delete, use File.delete() to actually delete it.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete%28%29

Comment: I just need to know how to make the String[] for the command

Comment: @user2996833 You should put that in your question. As-is your question is hard to understand.